# Não consigo gerar o a chave RSA para o Github: "Too many arguments"

Tags: git, ssh

Não consigo passar desta fase da instalação. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
Paulo ADM@PAULOADM-PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -c sismarq@castanhal.pa.gov.br
Too many arguments.
usage: ssh-keygen [-q] [-b bits] [-t dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa]
                  [-N new_passphrase] [-C comment] [-f output_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -i [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -e [-m key_format] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -y [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -c [-P passphrase] [-C comment] [-f keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -l [-v] [-E fingerprint_hash] [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -B [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -D pkcs11
       ssh-keygen -F hostname [-f known_hosts_file] [-l]
       ssh-keygen -H [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -R hostname [-f known_hosts_file]
       ssh-keygen -r hostname [-f input_keyfile] [-g]
       ssh-keygen -G output_file [-v] [-b bits] [-M memory] [-S start_point]
       ssh-keygen -T output_file -f input_file [-v] [-a rounds] [-J num_lines]
                  [-j start_line] [-K checkpt] [-W generator]
       ssh-keygen -s ca_key -I certificate_identity [-h] [-U]
                  [-D pkcs11_provider] [-n principals] [-O option]
                  [-V validity_interval] [-z serial_number] file ...
       ssh-keygen -L [-f input_keyfile]
       ssh-keygen -A
       ssh-keygen -k -f krl_file [-u] [-s ca_public] [-z version_number]
                  file ...
       ssh-keygen -Q -f krl_file file ...

Paulo ADM@PAULOADM-PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$
```

Comment: Use `-C` ao invés de `-c`. Veja se o erro é corrigido assim. Coloque o e-mail entre aspas também.

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente é um detalhe no comando.

Ao invés de usar `-c` (letra C em minúsculo) use `-C` (letra C em maiúsculo). Também corrija o comando e deixe o e-mail entre aspas. O comando final [deve ficar assim](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "sismarq@castanhal.pa.gov.br"
```